# HowTo Mock out ModalController in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework

#### Mock

```
export class ModalControllerMock {
    public create(param1,param2) {
        let rtn: Object = {};
        rtn['present'] = (() => true);
        return rtn;
    }; };
```

#### Production code:

```
 someFunc() {
        let modal = this.modalController.create(myComp, {
            stuff:stuff
        });
        modal.present();
    }
```

#### Error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modal.present') in src/test.ts (line 61262)

#### ModalController Implementation

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/modal/modal-controller.ts

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

#### In mocks.ts

```
import {ModalController} from "ionic-angular";
import { mockApp, mockConfig, mockDeepLinker } from 'ionic-angular/util/mock-providers';

export class ModalControllerMock {
    constructor() {
        return new ModalController(mockApp(), mockConfig(), mockDeepLinker());
    }
};
```

#### In spec files

`spyOn(modalControllerMock, "create").and.callThrough();`